# Run nodes in tabs of a terminal by roslaunch (e.g. roxterm)

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

we would like to run the processes started by roslaunch in individual tabs of an X-terminal. It's a bit against the concepts of rosout, but this allows to quickly switch between the output of nodes and also allows to interact with them during development.

Some X terminals allow to create a new tab from the shell, using e.g. roxterm --tab. This can be used as a launch prefix. However, roxterm --tab does not wait for the launched process to finish. As a result, roslaunch can no longer control it's child processes, and thinks the node exited directly.

I am thinking about a wrapper for roxterm --tab that behaves as expected by roslaunch. The wrapper must:

- Wait for the ROS node ran within the tab and return its exit code
- Forward signals to the ROS node
- Not register as a ROS node in any way

Is this enough, or is there anything else?

Best Regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276821/run-nodes-in-tabs-of-a-terminal-by-roslaunch-(e.g.-roxterm)/) by [Nicolas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4738/nicolas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-11-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noor](https://answers.ros.org/users/26717/noor/) on 2019-12-18**:
can we open mutilple tabs of ros prompts in single terminal window and without maximizing it in small size?

**Comment by [ermanas](https://answers.ros.org/users/43196/ermanas/) on 2019-12-18**:
You can do this by using the shortcut on the terminal: **CTRL + SHIFT + T** , if you're asking this by saying 'ros prompt'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem, and my solution was to create a bash file, where I created different tabs and launch nodes or launch files in each one of them.  I used gnome-terminal and had to add some sleeps in order to wait for the simulator to start running, but maybe you can also use them in the launch prefix. Here are the contents of the bash file.

```
   echo "Launching: roscore"
   gnome-terminal --window --maximize -x sh -c "roscore; exit"
   sleep 2
   rosparam set /prediction_time 10.0
   echo "Launching: stage_and_maps.launch"
   gnome-terminal --window --maximize -x sh -c "roslaunch stage_and_maps.launch; exit"
   echo "Waiting 10s left"
   sleep 10
   echo "Launching: prediction.launch"
   gnome-terminal --tab --maximize -x sh -c "roslaunch prediction.launch; exit"
```

Hope it helps!!

Mario

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2017-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1